# Mail format getting changed in recepient's mailbox in outlook

Tags: vbscript, outlook, format

I have written some code in vbscript to automatically send mails to a recepient using outlook,Everything is working fine but  i am having just one issue, The format what i have selected for the message body getting changed in the recepient's mail box.I used `font color- blue and font face -calibri but it got changed into Times new roman without any color`.

Any solution?

```
Set MyApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set MyItem = MyApp.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem
    With MyItem
            .To = "abc@com"
            .Subject = ""
            .ReadReceiptRequested = False

            .HTMLBody = "<font size='3' face='Calibri' color='#151B54'>Hi,Whatever written here got changed into plain text.<font>"




            .Attachments.Add "C:\Excels\"& objFso.GetFileName(objFile.path)
    End With
    MyItem.Display
    End if
```

Or is there any setting that i have to change in the outlook for the sent mails?

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly fine with me:

```
MailItem sendMail = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
        sendMail.Subject = "test";
        sendMail.To = SenderName; //or email
        sendMail.HTMLBody = "<font size='50' face='Verdana' color='#ff0000'>Hi,Whatever written here got changed into plain text.<font>";
        sendMail.Send();
```

When I send this to myself I recieve a big red text in verdana

Note that this is c# so I'm not sure if it will help you

EDIT:

One more thing: font size='3' won't work with me either. Because it's too small to display decently